# Does dataset sparsity affect rate of convergence of model solution?

Tags: machine-learning, sparse

I have a model with not too many ordinal data. The model performs at a 90% accuracy. I am thinking of adding 13 ordinal variables and transforming them using one hot encoder. The transformation will radically increase the sparsity of the model - the 13 ordinal variables will convert to around 100 variables.

Will this increase in sparsity have a negative effect on the model, theoretically speaking? I have had this happen in the past but did not want to immediately attribute it to the increased sparsity of the transformed dataset.

Is there a formal mathematical reason why a more sparse dataset can either decrease the rate of convergence of the solution of the model or cause the model to converge to a less optimal solution?

Comment: the sparsity you're referring to comes from the fact you're using "one-hot encodings"/"dummy variables", right? No, that's not generically going to be a problem (there are some exceptions :)).

Comment: @JohnMadden But the increase in the dimensionality of the dataset will surely decrease the learning rate of the model, specifically when using tree models where the tree size is fixed. Why would the rate of convergence of a model on a dataset with 10,000 sparse columns be the same as with 3 sparse columns?

Comment: What do you mean by "learning rate" in this context? And by "rate of convergence"? Computationally, like how long the algo takes to run? Or statistically, like how many data you need? It's true that from a computational perspective, it will take  longer with more variables. But it's not because those variables lots of zeros in them.

Comment: @JohnMadden A random forest model is constrained by the number of trees (a parameter value). So even though these sparse columns are generally 0, if the number of trees needed to converge to the optimal solution exceeds the parameter value specified (due to increase in dimensionality), then surely the model will not be an optimal one. And by the rate of convergence, I mean the time for the model to arrive at an optimal solution given the constraints.

Comment: Oh I see, you're wondering if it makes more sense to just plug in those variables as is (i.e. 13 ordinal ones) or just do a one-hot encoding. I was confused cause you kept asking about sparsity but that's a different topic. By breaking them up into one-hot encodings, you lose the ordinal nature of the data, so probably best to keep it as is.

Comment: @JohnMadden Thanks. What if it is not suitable to retain the ordinal nature of the data? For example, if my data is the day of the month, it would not make sense to use the raw ordinal data as the model will interpret 31st as 31 times more important than 1st

Comment: That's not how tree-based models work; rather individual trees will do something like "anything from 1st-20th of month is has predicted value $\mu_1$, anything between 20-24  is $\mu_2$ and anything $24-31$ is $\mu_3$"; what you're describing is an issue in linear models; so long as the data are naturally in an order it should be fine.

Comment: Ok great. Thank you very much :) Have a good day @JohnMadden